# Insert element into li with an id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert, html-lists

I have the following code

```
<ul id="box1">
  <li id="node3">Student C</li>
  <li id="node1">Student A</li>
  <li id="node2">Student B</li>
</ul>
```

I want to append into 'node1' some text field, how can I refer to it?

`$("li[id^=node]:last").attr("id")` - gives me the id of the object I added last, if I iterate through it, I get all the id's i need, but now I know the id and want to insert into it.

I have tried before() and after(), but its of no use, I need to insert the text file inside the `<li>` tag. So the final would be like:

```
<ul id="box1">
  <li id="node3">Student C</li>
  <li id="node1">Student A <input type="text" name="studAValue" style="margin-left:25px"/> </li>
  <li id="node2">Student B</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you have the value `node1`?

Comment: if your `id` is really unique, you should simply use `$("#node1")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
$("li[id^='node']:last").append('<b>test</b>');
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/uwXSR/

Answer (score 3):

Just refer to it by id:

```
$("#node1").append(
    '<input type="text" name="studAValue" style="margin-left:25px"/>');
```

Or in native JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("node1").innerHTML += 
    '<input type="text" name="studAValue" style="margin-left:25px"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/VfZuk/4/

```
$('#node1').append($('<input type="text" name="studAValue" style="margin-left:25px"/>'));
```